# Why Signed APK crashed on splash screen in Android

Tags: java, android

In Release signed apk, my app crashed when showing splash screen. I connect my phone with debugging mode and check logcat. Logcat shows me following error log,

```
    Process: com.hovata.petrolerp, PID: 22435
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at c4.e.c(:2)
        at f9.h.run(:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

What is the reason behind it? As debug apk, it works properly without any issue.

Comment: check if it works after ```minifyEnabled false``` in gradle file

Comment: You need to use your mapping file to determine what method is being called at `c4.e.c()`.

Answer (score -1):

I need more information, but I'll say to check if your files are all available in the release build. For example if you use "if(Build.DEBUG)" you run code that will only compile in a debug build/apk.

Comment: `I need more information` then it's best to ask for more information in a comment, i understand you might not have enough reputation to do that yet, but answering questions without enough information isn't going to get you there sooner, `"if(Build.DEBUG)" you run code that will only compile in a debug build/apk.` that's not true ? the code will compile exactly the same, the if condition just won't be triggered ? regardless, this is probably an issue caused by code obfuscation